# Richfaces Primefaces CSS Conflict with enableControlSkinning

Tags: css, richfaces, primefaces

I am trying a sample JSF project using both richfaces (4.0) and primefaces (2.2).

but when i use the enableControlSkinning like the following

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Some of the Primefaces component are not shown properly (yet to see the functionality of the components) ..
I think the css is conflicting.
but if i set enableControlSkinning to false, primefaces component works fine...

any suggestion to set the enableControlSkinning without any trouble ?

one snapshot of a primeface command button ...
Primefaces theme : home
Richfaces skin : glassX
but the p:commandButton on hover is showing both the themes ...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well automatic skinning of standard controls probably detects PrimeFaces controls as "standard". So you turn of automatic skinning and use class skinning provided.

Web.xml should be like this, replace your 4 lines with this: (notice first param is **false**!)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And use rfs-ctn style class on components that you want to skin

Copied from RF manual: [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_standard_controls-Skinning_with_the_rfs-ctn_class)